# If $A$ is symmetric, then $I+\epsilon A \succ 0$ if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

From Richard Bellman's *Introduction to Matrix Analysis*:

> If $A$ is symmetric, then $I+\epsilon A$ is positive definite if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.

---

**Attempt**: For $x\neq 0$ and $\epsilon >0$, we can set $x=Sy$ where $S$ consists of the eigenvectors of $A$ to obtain

$$x^T (I+\epsilon A) x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N x_i^2+\epsilon\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \lambda_i y_i^2$$

as $A$ is diagonalizable. Then I considered $\epsilon < \frac{1}{N\alpha}$ where $\alpha=\min\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N\}$, but this only prevails provided $x^Tx\geq 1$. Any advice for picking $\epsilon$ here? The other route is to show eigenvalues of $I+\epsilon A$ are all positive which (I believe) are of the form $1+\epsilon \lambda _i$ - we can do it this way by setting

$$\epsilon < \frac{1}{\max\{|\lambda_1|,\dots,|\lambda_N|\}}.$$

Comment: I'm curious. What if A is negative definite but symmetric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** You are taking a very intricate approach to the problem. This could be made to work, but I would suggest instead that work along the following lines.

1. Note/show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $x \neq 0$, $\left|\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}\right| \leq C$.
2. Note that $x^T(I + \epsilon A)x = x^Tx + \epsilon \cdot x^TAx$ and select $\epsilon$ accordingly.

Comment: For 1, I let $C$ be the the maximum absolute eigenvalue. Then for 2, I see that $x^Tx-\epsilon\cdot x^TAx>0\iff 1> \frac{\epsilon\cdot x^TAx}{x^Tx}$ which holds for $\epsilon <\frac{1}{C}$. Thanks (if I understood that correctly)!

Comment: How is $x^T(I + \epsilon A)x = x^Tx - \epsilon \cdot x^TAx$?

Comment: @Paichu Of course that should be a $+$, see my edit

Comment: @pSrIoGcNeAsLs That's perfect. You're welcome!

Comment: @pSrIoGcNeAsLs If that's a "+" sign, wouldn't that make the right hand side in your equivalence relation $1 > -\frac{\epsilon x^T Ax}{x^T x}$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann So, effectively does perhaps this prove that any symmetric matrix is a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) for the set of positive definite matrices?

Comment: @pSrIoGcNeAsLs If $\epsilon < \frac{1}{C}$, the implication is $\frac{\epsilon x^T A x}{x^T x} < 1$. To get to the conclusion, you assume that $- \frac{\epsilon x^T A x}{x^T x} \leq  \frac{\epsilon x^T A x}{x^T x} < 1$, which may not hold for general symmetric matrix $A$. Or maybe I'm just missing something silly.

Comment: @Paichu Sorry, that should have been $\left|\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}\right| \leq C$. We can use the fact that $\lambda_\min x^Tx \leq x^TAx \leq \lambda_{\max} x^TAx$, or one could make a compactness argument.

Comment: $\lambda_{\text{max}}x^Tx$

Comment: I don't quite see why we need the absolute value. If I take $x=Sy$ as I mentioned above, then I get $x^TAx=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \lambda_i y_i^2$ and the bottom becomes $(Sy)^T(Sy)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N y_i^2$ if I normalize the matrix of eigenvectors $S$ and the inequality follows without the absolute value?

Comment: @pSrIoGcNeAsLs Your method works. With my approach, the upper bound $C \geq \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$ is technically insufficient; what we really need is the existence of a lower bound. You could come to this conclusion using eigenvalues, or you could use a topological argument